# fetch numbered rows in hive table

Tags: hive

Consider I have 100 rows in hive table, How to fetch 30 rows which are in between 50 to 80? I remember there are few commands/queries in other languages, are there any commands/queries in Hive.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no such functionality  you have to write custom query  using CTE and window function ..

Comment: Side note: SQL does **not** give any guarantee that two similar SELECT queries will return the rows in the **same order**. That's true for every database. It's even more true with Hive because of the distributed nature of MapReduce processing. So if you want to "page" your results, you need a unique key and an ORDER BY (implicit in  windowing) every time

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT id, aaa, bbb, ccc,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rank__
  FROM mydb.mytable
 ) windowed__
WHERE rank__ BETWEEN 51 AND 80
ORDER BY rank__
```

That will do the trick, provided you have an "id" in your table *(i.e. some unique key, or unique combination of keys)*.

But if you run that several times just to page your results, performance will be terrible -- that means a full MapReduce job every time.